# Android, Using an Async task to grab text from url

Tags: java, android, url, android-asynctask

Right I think as far as this goes you should consider me a complete noob, I am in way over my head.

I have attempted to cobble what I understand about this together from several partial tutorials each dealing with a different aspect that I want to do.

Long and short of it, all I want to do is get text read from a URL to display in a text view, my understanding is that I need an AsyncTask to do that since the 3.0 update.

Any help on where I am going wrong would be great as I don't understand what's causing the error and how to fix.

I do know that the code contained within the try and catch of the doInBackground works on its own before the 3.0 update. Whether this too needs to be modified to work with an Async however I don't know.

I also imagine that other issues will probably arise once this one is sorted, if anyone spots something glaringly obvious I would be grateful if you could point it out.

```
String Event;
TextView eventText;
TextView titleText;

String HTML;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newevent);

    titleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Title);
    eventText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Event);

    new eventupdate().execute();


}

public class eventupdate extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... url) {

        try {

            Thread.sleep(4000);                 

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
                    "http://masterzangetsu.eu/Apps/rocksoctest"); // URL!
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet,
                    localContext);
            String result = "";

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line + "\n";
                HTML = result;
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        eventText.setText("" + HTML);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


}
```

And the LogCat error is:

```
W/dalvikvm(394): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
E/AndroidRuntime(394): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
E/AndroidRuntime(394): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

E/AndroidRuntime(394): Caused by: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2932)
E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:629)
E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at android.widget.ScrollView.requestLayout(ScrollView.java:1291)
E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:257)
E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:5521)
E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2724)
E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2592)
E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2567)
E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at com.MasterZangetsu.kentrocksoc.nextEvent$eventupdate.doInBackground(nextEvent.java:81)
E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at com.MasterZangetsu.kentrocksoc.nextEvent$eventupdate.doInBackground(nextEvent.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
```

Comment: <shamelessplug> See here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqFkkXMwWDg for a Video Walkthrough of some source code that explains the AsyncTask pulling data from web in more detail. Hopefully after watching you'll have a better idea of how and why it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line here

```
 eventText.setText("" + HTML);
```

is causing your problem. You can't update the `UI` from `doInBackground()`. It has to be done in one of the other methods or sent back to a main `Activity` method. Here you could do it in `onPostExecute()`

[Read through the AyncTask Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

There are different ways of accomplishing this but you could change your `AsyncTask` to return result to `onPostExecute()`

```
public class eventupdate extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> // change last param
```

then add `onPostExecute()` method and change `return` statement in `doInBackground()`

```
public class eventupdate extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
         eventText.setText("" + result);
}

 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
   // do your work
   return HTML;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i added the line to the 

protected void onPostExecute(){
   
   eventText.setText("" + HTML);
   
  }
but now it does nothing

Comment: no as in nothing happens ... nothing is returned and im getting no errors

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see that part of the comment. Did you change the `return` statement of `doInBackground()` as I suggested? And verify that `HTML` has a value in `doInBackground()`

Comment: Ah perfect! I hadn't seen that bit either somehow, worked like a charm, at least I was closer that I thought I was with my original code

Comment: Yep, you weren't too far off. You just have to remember that you can't update the `UI` from a background `thread`. It takes some time to fully understand the `AsyncTask`, at least if did for me. And I've had to read through the docs many times but once you understand it goes much more smoothly