# Passing JSON array - Android

Tags: java, android, json

I'm writing an simple web service, using php and mysql as server and android app as client to retrieve data.

My server side returns this JSON array when I make a query.

```
"customers":[
    {"firstName":"Jason", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Joan", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Jennifer", "lastName":"Jones"}
]
```

My question is how to parse this JSON array into ArrayList for using later.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending and Parsing JSON Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-objects)

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed this way:

```
String jsonStr; // your JSON string
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String firstname = jsonObj.getString("firstname");
    String lastname = jsonObj.getString("lastname");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your array list of type myData**

```
 List<myData> listData = new ArrayList<myData>(); 
 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("your response json string");

                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    listData.add(new myData(jsonObj.getString("firstname"),jsonObj.getString("lastname")));
                }
// your ArrayList is ready, and you can use it anytime.
```

**Your data structure for firstname and lastname**

**myData.java**

```
public class myData {
String firstName, lastName;
myData(String fName, String lName) {
    this.firstName = fName;
    this.lastName = lName;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GSON

```
        public class Customer{
            String firstName;
            String lastName;

            public static class List extends ArrayList<Customer>{

            }
        }
        public static Customer.List getCustomersList(String jsonString){
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            return gson.fromJson(jsonString, Customer.List.class);
        }
```

Comment: What if I want to parse json from a link?

Comment: You need to write an Async Task to get the string like mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15835425/1402525

Answer (score -1):

Use libraries like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) or [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome).

Comment: Don't post link as answer dear.!!

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this without  `GSON` or `Jackson`

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  listCustomer= new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> mapCustomer = new HashMap<String, String>();
        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        mapCustomer.put("firstname", jsonObj.getString(firstname));
        mapCustomer.put("lastname", jsonObj.getString(lastname));

        listCustomer.add(mapCustomer);

    }
```